# Positional accuracy assessment methods in qgis

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, streets

I'm doing an quality assessment of openstreetmap's street data. As a comparism dataset I have to use an administrative dataset, which is highly accurate and comes in polygons. Here's a sneak peek:

[image]

So far I've examined positional accuracy via goodchild and hunter's buffer method. But that's not enough content and I'm struggling to find more evaluation methods I could build some models with. I came across hausdorff distance, but a (required) conversion from polygons to polylines didn't work out well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't really have a question here.  Detailing the issue you had with polygon-polyline conversion *would* be an appropriate, focused GIS SE question.

Comment: Okay let me try to be more clear about it:

I'm looking for ideas to evaluate data quality with a polygon as reference data set and a polyline as an assessment data set.

Comment: Did you check http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Research? This is a comprehensive list of resarch done in the osm environment.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to make clarifications. Take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how GIS SE works.